# javascript object.checked not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

I am using the following code to uncheck selected check boxes on page refresh.

```
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
{
object[i].checked = false;
}
```

The validation after refresh will work but the checkboxes will stay as selected.(Tick wont go)

Please Help.

Comment: It works just fine for me in IE11. [See my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ue9pQ/1/). I've used you're exact code. If you're having issues, it isn't with the code you've posted. It might help if you showed us where the `object` variable is being defined; my guess is that it isn't populated properly when it gets to the code in your question. As for why that would be, I can only speculate.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute checked of the checkbox didn't use value true or false. ([Input checked attribute on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp))

In order to uncheck the checkboxes, you have to remove the attribute from the element:

```
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    if (object[i].hasAttribute("checked")) {
        object[i].removeAttribute("checked");
    }  
}
```

Obviously, you can check the checkboxes by adding the attribute to the element:

```
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    if (!object[i].hasAttribute("checked")) {
        object[i].addAttribute("checked");
    }  
}
```

This will work on every single browser by the way.

Comment: There is no such thing as "addAttribute" - you can do setAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
{
object[i].checked = "off";
}
```